# Showing specific categories

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, plugins, categories

I'd like to show only specific wordpress categories (with their sub-categories nested), so for example:

- Main Category 1

  - Sub Category 1.1
  - Sub Category 1.2
- Main Category 5

  - Sub Category 2.1
  - Sub Category 2.2

... I can hardcode it inside the sidebar template, but I'd like to know if there's any existing plugin/widget that allows this so I can easily manage category selection/update via admin panel.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [wp-list-categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) tag. I'm assuming you're customising your template and this came up?

The function has enough parameters to customise it as you need.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using wp-list-categories but it doesn't show sub-categories although I have it enabled, what could it be?

Comment: If you used the wp-list-categories function and it doesn't work try checking that the CSS isn't hiding it for some reason?

eg. If they are embedded lists there may be a CSS height on an <li> not allowing the sub <ul> to show?

Comment: Can you post the actual invocation of the function as a snippet?